# Problema para configurar angulajs no Nginx

Tags: angularjs, linux, nginx, centos

Não estou conseguindo configurar o angulajs no Nginx. Estou usando uma maquina linux Centos7 e gostaria de configurar o angular para poder aprender.

Segue o arquivo de configuração do nginx.html

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
   worker_connections 1024;
 }

 http {
  log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404
    #try_files $uri /index.html
    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    autoindex on;
    #rewrite (.*) index.html last;
    #expires -1;
    #add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    #add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Ainda não consegui.

Comment: Você está seguindo algum tutorial? Você precisa mostrar um código de erro para que eu possa ajudar